# Placeholder text shouldn't be removed upon entering text in TextInput React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

I need some help in using TextInput react native.

What I am trying to achieve is I need to append the "months" text inside TextInput upon the user starts typing in the form field. If you look at the below screen shot for Tenure and Paid EMI the values are 123 and 12. I need to get like this "123 months" and "12 months" dynamically months should be added upon user entering the values.

For example if user is typing 2 then it should be displayed as "2 months" and if the user deletes 2, then default placeholder text should be displayed "36 months".

More importantly "months" should be non-editable, user should be able to only enter or update the numerical values. For example: If the value is "12 months" in the TextInput and the user wants to update it "32 months". Then he/she clicks on the TextInput field and clicks backspace 2 times and then enters new value "32". In the ui it will be displayed as "32 months".

[Note:- Only I need numerical values to be captured, I don't want the month value to be captured. It need to be displayed only for end user in the TextInput. "32 months" will be shown in the form field, but the state value should be only "32".

[image]

[image]

[EDITED-1 Added Code]
**Render Function:-**

```
            <View style={{marginTop:height(2),width:width(90)}}>
           <View style={{height:height(3),marginLeft:width(1)}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize:16,fontFamily:"Ubuntu-Bold"}}>Tenure</Text>
                </View> 
              <View style={{marginTop: height(1),width:width(90),alignItems:"center"}}>
            <TouchableOpacity  style={{width:width(90),flexDirection:"row",backgroundColor:"#F6F6F6",alignItems:"center",justifyContent:"center",height:height(6),borderRadius:12}}>
           
           <TextInput placeholder="36 months"  
                      textAlign={"center"} 
                      value={this.state.tenure}
                      maxLength={3}
                      onChangeText={this.onTenureChanged.bind(this)}
                      keyboardType="number-pad"/>
       </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>
            </View>

            <View style={{marginTop:height(4.5),width:width(90),bottom: height(3)}}>
           <View style={{height:height(3),marginLeft:width(1)}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize:16,fontFamily:"Ubuntu-Bold"}}>Paid EMI</Text>
                </View> 
              <View style={{marginTop: height(1),width:width(90),alignItems:"center"}}>
            <TouchableOpacity  style={{width:width(90),flexDirection:"row",backgroundColor:"#F6F6F6",alignItems:"center",justifyContent:"center",height:height(6),borderRadius:12}}>
           
           <TextInput placeholder="15 months"  
                      textAlign={"center"} 
                      maxLength={3}
                      value={this.state.paidemi}
                      onChangeText={this.onPaidEMIChanged.bind(this)}
                      keyboardType="number-pad"/>
       </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>
            </View>
```

**Javascript Functions:-**

```
onTenureChanged(itemValue){
  this.setState({tenure: itemValue})
}

onPaidEMIChanged(itemValue){
  this.setState({paidemi: itemValue})
}
```

Comment: Prabu, if I were you, I would consider putting the code in a sandbox and share it here. or put the code itself here. right now, its just an explanation so its hard for folks to help you.

Comment: Okay, Sure. I am adding it now. Actually, I have explained the usecase.

Comment: Use Case is explained but when people see code, that means, you put some effort into solving the issue yourselves. here, the idea is that you put some effort, then got stuck. if you are just saying use case, it comes across like you are just using the community to solve the problems without any effort from your side. hence the insistence on code.

Comment: Thanks.! Jay. I have added the code.

Comment: This is tricky. Try this https://snack.expo.io/@saachitech/7870eb and try to edit the number. Let me know if this help.

Comment: As you suggested, similary whether can I try like this, I am not sure whether it will work or not.

           <TextInput placeholder="15 months"
                      textAlign={"center"}
                      maxLength={3}
                      value={this.state.paidemi+' months'}
                      onChangeText={this.onPaidEMIChanged.bind(this)}
                      keyboardType="number-pad"/>`